# audio+video processing module in kurento

Tags: webrtc, kurento

[Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/) has lots of examples of writing kms-filter modules that process video frames, but none that show how to process audio+video.  Additionally, `kurento-module-scaffold.sh` seems to only generate module projects that receive a `cv::Mat` or a `GstVideoFrame`.

Kurento itself says

> As a differential feature, Kurento Media Server also provides advanced
>   media processing capabilities involving computer vision, video
>   indexing, augmented reality and **speech analysis**.

so it seems like it should be possible, but I can't see any way to get at the audio in their API.

So my question is: can this be done?  If so, how?